# Jquery: elements value is not coming correct

Tags: jquery

I trying to get the all input elements having `name="choices"` before submit. And i want to check the values of those elements before submiting the form .
The problem is instead of getting the 0 ,1 ,2 which is values of elements i'm getting `undefined` (3 times).

**form**

```
<form action="/check"  method="post" id="mform1" >
<div id="id_poll_choices" >
                A). <input type="text"  name="choices" value="0"><br>
                B). <input type="text"  name="choices" value="1"><br>
                C). <input type="text"  name="choices" value="2"><br>
            </div>  
<input type="submit" id="id_submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#mform1').submit(function(){

            $( "input[name*='choices']" ).each(function(index, elm){
                alert(elm.val)
            });
    });
```

alert showing `undefined`.

what could be the issue here ?

Comment: You are repeating DOM id `id_ch`...which is incorrect..

Comment: Also, while it's legal to reuse `name`, in this case it's probably not what you want. You should use `name="choices[]"` so the server will get an array of all the names.

Comment: Have a look at the examples in the `.each` documentation. I think it's pretty clear: http://api.jquery.com/each/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elm` is a DOM element. It doesn't have any `val` property.

Replace

```
 alert(elm.val)
```

with

```
 alert($(elm).val())
```

or

```
 alert(elm.value) // better
```

A few notes :

- Pay also attention to the id : only one element can have a given id.
- You should use `"input[name='choices']"` instead of `"input[name*='choices']"` as selector. Both work here but one is faster and more selective. Unless your elements should have different names of course (which is the general practice apart for radio buttons)
- The element is `this` in the callback
- life is easier with `console.log` instead of `alert` ([read more](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console))

So I'd suggest this

```
$('#mform1').submit(function(){
        $( "input[name='choices']" ).each(function(){
            console.log(this.value);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#mform1').submit(function(){
            $( "input[name*='choices']" ).each(function(index, elm){
                alert(elm.value);
            });
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aAvuY/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** Don't use same id's for all inputs. Id's should be unique.